# 'None' is Unicode and not NoneType in python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

If I have a statement like so:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MYTABLE(name, age, hair_color) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" , ("Alice", 24, None))

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE Id=?", (1,))

print cursor.fetchone()[2] is None   # This is false! I want this to be true.
```

Retrieving the hair_color will be `u'None'` rather than a `NoneType`.

I know I can just do a simple check to see if it's equal to a unicode "None" but rather than specifying this condition, is there a way to tell python that I want fields that have "None" to be replaced with a NoneType when I do a fetchone() or fetchall()?

MYTABLE is `(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, age INTEGER, hair_color TEXT)`

Comment: What is your definition of MYTABLE?

Comment: Isn't this because `("%s"% None) is 'None'` (rather than `None`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry guys, I just figured it out.

As it turns out, I have to explicitly tell sqlite3 that I want python to automatically convert between types.

So the solution was to do this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
```